# Get url from MvcSiteMapProvider by key with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I usually get the url from a node with the following code:
`MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("AccountDetailsKey").Url`

Now I have a node with a parameter. But how can I get the url for that node. So in the below example we need the url of the "AccountDetailsKey" node.

`<mvcSiteMapNode key="BeherenAccountKey" title="Zoeken accounts" controller="BeherenAccount" action="BeherenAccount">
   <mvcSiteMapNode key="AccountDetailsKey" title="Account details" controller="BeherenAccount" action="AccountDetails" preservedRouteParameters="gebruikersnaam" visibility="!SiteMapHelper,!MainMenu,*" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>`

Details action:

```
[Route("account/details/{gebruikersnaam}")]
public ActionResult AccountDetails(string gebruikersnaam)
{
    return this.View((object)gebruikersnaam);
}
```

De routeconfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Offcourse we could use the following for generating an url to the details page with regular MVC razor code:

```
@Url.Action("AccountDetails", "BeherenAccount", new { gebruikersnaam = User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Replace("domain\\", "") })
```

The thing is that **we don't want to use action and controller names in our code**. We want to generate all the urls from the sitemap. Everything works fine in the whole application but can't get this details page working. We don't have a DynamicNodeProvider because we don't care for separate titles, seo etc because it is an administrator application.

The application shows the loggedin user in the main menu (_Layout page) and this is an url to his own detail page.

So when the loggedin user has username "abc", the details url must be "account/details/abc".

Answer (score 0):

When using `preservedRouteParameters`, the `SiteMap` does not automatically generate the route values that are supposed to be placed onto the node. They come from the current request of the page. Normally, when doing this you are expected to provide URLs using `ActionLink`, `Action`, `RouteLink`, or `UrlHelper`, as would typically be the case when doing CRUD operations, since the links would need to be derived from the database data.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Gebruikersnaam", "AccountDetails", "BeherenAccount", new { gebruikersnaam = "Value" }, null)
```

Alternatively, if no route value named `gebruikersnaam` exists in the current request, you can supply it manually.

```
string url;
var node = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("AccountDetailsKey");

if (node != null)
{
    node.RouteValues["gebruikersnaam"] = "Value";
    url = node.Url;
}
```

When you set a route value outside of an `ISiteMapNodeProvider` or dynamic node provider, the value that is set will only last for the lifetime of the current request.

> **NOTE:** I really don't understand the exact problem you are having with the above code. In my test project it is working fine regardless of what page you are on. If you want to investigate further, you can use the code from [Controlling URL Behavior](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Controlling-URL-Behavior#using-net-routing) to mimic how the `SiteMapNodeUrlResolver` uses the MVC `UrlHelper`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution but it doesn't work. I only get "BeherenAccount/AccountDetails" I placed this code in my _Layout file. When I navigate to the details page then the code works. I think that is because it sees the "gebruikersnaam" (dutch for username) in the request. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you haven't inserted the call to `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` ***before*** your default route. You can confirm this by placing `@Html.ActionLink("Gebruikersnaam", "AccountDetails", "BeherenAccount", new { gebruikersnaam = "Value" }, null)` on your view. But then, I don't really see the point in getting `MvcSiteMapProvider` involved if all you want is the URL, since MVC has all of the functionality you need to resolve it (`ActionLink`, `RouteLink`, and `UrlHelper`).

Comment: I edited my question for more explanation. When I try your code in this answer, the url works if you are on the details page. But this is because the request is filled. The problem is that the url in the main menu changes from the logged in user ("abc") to the selected user in example "xyz".

Comment: You could try setting `includeAmbientValuesInUrl="true"` on the node, which will make it use the real request context when generating the URL instead of a fake one based on the home page. This was done specifically to [keep parameters from bleeding over from the current request](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/213). But other than that, when using `preservedRouteParameters` it is expected that you supply your own navigation from MVC because it won't work on its own - its not designed to.

Comment: I just can't get it to work. So just used the standard MVC way like you said: `<a href="@Url.Action("AccountDetails", "BeherenAccount", new { gebruikersnaam = User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Replace("domain\\", "") })">@User.Identity.Name</a>`. If you adjust the Answer I will mark it as answer

Comment: I created a test project and I finally found the reason why it isn't working for me. We have Security trimming enabled. When I add `<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true"/>` to my test project the url doesn't work. When I set the value to `false` everything is working like you said. So standard mvc application with the latest version of mvc 5 and mvcsitemapprovider. I can send you the test project project if you like?

Comment: Now that you mention it, this is the same issue as [#272](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/272), so a test project is not necessary. The issue is that accessing the `SiteMap` object directly triggers the `AuthorizeAttributeAclModule`, which causes the URL to be resolved and request cached prior to being able to set any values in the `SiteMapNode`. There is no fix for this at present (other than creating a custom `SiteMap` and overriding `ReturnNodeIfAccessible` to turn off security trimming at that stage).

Comment: Unfortunately, fixing that in the real project would be a major breaking change in behavior.

Comment: Good to hear that i'm not missing something. I stick with the default `@Url.Action` method because I believe that this is the most natural way to solve this issue for now. Thanks for the help! It's a great extension for my application.